# change icons on sensation lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen-shortcuts, htc-sensation

I've just got a HTC sensation and I've worked out how to change the icons on the home screens, but is there a way to change the icons on the lock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **this is possible without apps**. The icons on the lockscreen are the same ones that you chose for the home screen:

Here you see the icons I originally had on both screens:
[image: Original Home and lock screen]

By changing the apps on my home screen adjacent to all apps, this change is mirrored on the lock screen:

[image: Modified home and lock screen]

To change the icons adjacent to all apps on your home screen, long-press them until you can move them around then drop the old icons either into the trash can (that appears when you long press) or into a free space on another part of the home screen.  You can then replace it with an icon of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are various lock screen apps on the market, but so far the best I've seen is [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker), very customizable and in my opinion worth the small price.