# How to change/remove icons on LG lock screen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, customization, lg-optimus-l5

I have `LG Optimus L5` with `Android 4.0.3`. When `screen is locked` there are four icons (Phone, Messaging, E-mail, Camera) in the bottom of it. If I tap on it and slide, screen unlocks and the tapped app is launched.

I know there are apps for [customizing lock screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/change-icons-on-sensation-lock-screen) but I couldn't find any free to help me with my LG.

How can I remove or change this icons on my LG device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. In **Settings > Lock Screen** you can configure your Lock Screen. There are options to change the way screen is unlocked, to change wallpaper and to change widget and shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the screen. On the bottom left there should be a symbol with three horizontal lines.Touch that. Go to Lock Screen.Tap Shortcuts. The four options should appear. Touch which app you want to remove, the list of apps will come up, scroll until you find the app you want to use and tap on it. Do the same for other apps to remove and add. When finished press save. You can also remove the apps by tapping Delete Shortcut at the very top of the apps list